# check if the current post is one of the recent 5 post

Tags: php, wordpress

I am making a code in which i wanted to check that the current post which i have opened is one of the recent 5 post in word press or not . i know the current post id can be get by

`get_the_ID();`

and can check if post exist by

```
if ( FALSE === get_post_status( $id ) ) {
  // The post does not exist
} else {
  // The post exists
}
```

but how to check that value if it is one of those recent 5 post or not ? Because every now and then the recent post will change .

Comment: So get five recent posts and check if current post id exists among them

Comment: try http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_recent_posts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would loop through the top 5 posts. Then check if there is any match.

```
function isRecentPost($id) {
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts(array('numberposts' => '5'));
    foreach ($recent_posts as $post) {
        if($post['ID'] == $id)
        {
            return true;
        }
    } 
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this approach . Functions are always awesome

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve from posts with numberofposts=5 and ORDERBY post_date  Then loop through these five posts and compare individual IDs with the current post ID

```
$args = array(
'numberposts' => 5,
'offset' => 0,
'category' => 0,
'orderby' => 'post_date',
'order' => 'DESC',
'include' => ,
'exclude' => ,
'meta_key' => ,
'meta_value' =>,
'post_type' => 'post',
'post_status' => 'draft, publish, future, pending, private',
'suppress_filters' => true ); 
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args, $output ); //$output is an optional argument

foreach($recent_posts as $recent_post)
{
  if($recent_post['ID'] == $your_current_id)
  {
     //HAPPY
  }
}
```

Comment: Would you be able to provide a code? In that way, your answer may become much clearer.